# Address Book Search - Which Data structure i should use when large data

Tags: java, design-patterns, database-design

I want to design Address book with following fields

**UID    Name  PhoneNumber1  PhoneNumber2**

UID is to identify the name uniquely. Lets say i want to save 2 million records. 
Now i want to structure how to save this records, so that it can be searchable by both Name and phoneNumber.

Which data structure and search technique i should go with.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What if you have conflicting names?
John Smith could return multiple times.
It appears that you are better off just using PhoneNumber1/PhoneNumber2 as your search variables.

I'd recommend a [HashTable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) to do this, as it allows O(1) for searching, and with 2 million records, you don't want it to take forever to find someone.

Answer (score 1):

Normalise that to the following tables and columns:

- **Names**: `UID, Name`
- **PhoneNumbers**: `UID, SN, PhoneNumber`

  - SN serial number, so 1 or 2 (and in the future, 3 to 1000 as well)

Each search you do should run two queries, one for each table (or one UNION query on both tables)

```
SELECT   UID, Name
FROM     Names
WHERE    Name = '%<search string>%'

SELECT   UID, PhoneNumber
FROM     PhoneNumbers
WHERE    PhoneNumber = '%<search string>%'
ORDER BY UID  # so that multiple matches with same user appear together
```

Combining the results of both queries can be done in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you design a class `AddressBook`

```
class AddressBook{
private Integer uuid;
private String name;
private Integer phoneNumber1;
private Integer phoneNumber2;

//getters & setters 

}
```

Create a AddressBook Table in your database with the corresponding fields. `uuid` will be the primary key. Persist the AddressBook object.

To search by name

```
select * from AddressBook where name ="something";
```

To search by phone number

```
select * from AddressBook where phoneNumber1="something";
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what are your main targets :

If requirement dvelopment is done and you have decided to use a relational data model for data storage and retrieval then @aneroid answer is an option. 
Have in mind that:

- Using `WHERE Name = '%<search string>%'` will force a considerable cost on RDMS engine. You may seek advanced [full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/full-text-search/info) techniques in large scale data, based on your RDBMS.
- If performance is the main target, using [relational in memory databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_in-memory_databases) will be an option.

In case RDBMS can be skipped, then java lang data structures 
will come in handy, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267572/fastest-data-structure-for-contains-in-java) they are forged in terms of time complexity.