# What is the best data structure to implement a 2D Matrix with String data type?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have huge table data with 150 rows and 10 Columns, each column has String data. After storing the data, I have to traverse as well to find a particular value. So, I am looking for answers to the best data structure in this case in terms of performance, flexibility of traversing.

I have thought of Array, ArrayList, Hashmap.

Also, I have found similar questions on SO but they don't answer my question.

EDIT: The data is a mixture of Alphabets and Integers. Cannot be sorted and contains duplicates as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest data structure for contains() in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267572/fastest-data-structure-for-contains-in-java)

Comment: How often do you need to traverse it? 150*10 is really not a big deal unless you traverse it thousands of times. And in that case you should specify the use case better.

Comment: You have to describe more  - what operations are needed? Array is the best for traversing. But would you need to search? Add (extending limits)?

Comment: @IngoBürk - Say it is 10 times in a single program run.

Comment: @MBo - I need to search only. No additions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716597/array-or-list-in-java-which-is-faster

Comment: actually a mixture of Alphabets and Integers can be sorted pretty easly

Comment: @Haxor 150 * 10 * 10 = 15000. I wouldn't worry about efficiency too much here. Think of what Knuth said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems then for such table size combination `2D Array[][] + Hashmap` would be an excellent choice. Simple and effective.

Array contains values and allows to traverse the table in any order.

HashMap contains pairs `<String; TPoint>` (coordinates in array - Row/Col pair).

If you need only to know whether the table contains some string, then don't store coordinates in Map.

I think that `Guava Table` proposed by @krzyk, provides similar functionality (don't know about performance)

Answer (score 3):

Guava has a [`Table`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) structure that looks like you could use, it has [`containsValue(...)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html#containsValue(java.lang.Object)) method to find particular value, and you can also traverse it.

Here's a general [explanation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table) of the `Table`:

> Typically, when you are trying to index on more than one key at a time, you will wind up with something like `Map<FirstName, Map<LastName, Person>>`, which is ugly and awkward to use. Guava provides a new collection type, Table, which supports this use case for any "row" type and "column" type.

You would be most probably interested in following implementation of the `Table` interface:

> `ArrayTable`, which requires that the complete universe of rows and columns be specified at construction time, but is backed by a two-dimensional array to improve speed and memory efficiency when the table is dense. `ArrayTable` works somewhat differently from other implementations

Answer (score 1):

just in this case, I would use a String[][] because you can access the elements with a complexity of O(1)

but as I said, only in this case. If the number of the rows or columns is dynamically modified then I'd use `List<List<String>>`, more exactly ArrayList

Comment: Note that author needs also `to find a particular value`

Comment: yes, and in either way he can find it
using array would be like this: array[43][54]
and using arraylist would be like this: list.get(43).get(54)

Comment: You are writing about getting the value from specific cell. To find if unordered array contains given string, one should walk through **all** C*R cells

Comment: yes, you are right, but unfortunately I can't think of a better solution atm, but your solution should be better than mine