# Generate all possible strings optimization

Tags: java, string, loops, random, while-loop

I have to generate a list of every string possible (given a specific string to pick characters from), the first method I came up with is this one:

```
public String getRandomLetters(Integer size, String range){
    String word = "";
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        word += range.charAt(r.nextInt(range.length()));
    } 

    return word;
}
```

Using like this: `getRandomLetters(2, "abc");`

This will return a string of 2 letters.

Now, with this given range I have to generate a list of random strings. This list of words must not have repeatable words, must start by 1 character and when out of possibilities just add another.

Im trying this:

```
public List<String> getListOfRandomWords(Integer listLenght){
    String range = "abc"; //abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    Integer rangeLenght = range.length();

    List<String> words = new ArrayList();
    int counter = 1;

    int possibilities = (int) Math.pow(Double.valueOf(rangeLenght), Double.valueOf(counter));

    String word = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < listLenght; i++) {
        word = getRandomLetters(counter, range);

        while (words.contains(word)) {
            if(words.size() == possibilities){
                counter++;
                possibilities += (int) Math.pow(Double.valueOf(rangeLenght), Double.valueOf(counter));
            }
            word = getRandomLetters(counter, range);
        }

        words.add(word);
    }

    return words;
}
```

To run this:

```
        List<String> testList = getListOfRandomWords(20);

        for (String block : testList) {
            System.out.println(block);
        }
```

Output:

```
c
b
a
cc
ca
aa
bb
ba
ac
bc
ab
cb
bcc
cca
bac
aab
bab
cbb
baa
bcb
```

**The output is ok and method works properly, my only concern is `while(randomLetters.contains(randomLetter))`, is this the most optimal way to check for duplicate values?**

PD: I can't use a sum to make this easier and generate the strings in order, they must come in random order.

Comment: Is it really necessary to generate the strings randomly? To generate all possible strings is much easier if you do it systematically.

Comment: You want to read how to do permutations. Using random in there for sure makes your code an order of magnitude more complicated (and slower)... And doesn't add any value.

Comment: there is `Collections.shuffle()` available to you to do this potentially much easier.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you want randomness at all. If you really want *every* possible combination, then just iterate through all the combinations and permutations. Randomess has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Henry yes... its a requirement :P

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy cant do that, the shorter words have to be on top

Answer (score 0):

Using `List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();` and `words.contains(word)` is definitely not the most optimal way to check for duplicate values.  This is an O(N²) operation, since you have an O(N) search for each word, and you're looping over that one or more times for every word you add.

`Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();` and `words.contains(word)` should be significantly faster.

Of course, if you want to maintain the order you've added the words in, instead of some random order, you'd want to use: `Set<String> words = new LinkedHashSet<>();`.

Use `return new ArrayList<>(words)` to convert the returned value back to a `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to cycle through all permutations is [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm).

I don't understand it completely, as I have not read the proof behind it, but it definitely works, and cycles through all permutations exactly once.  Using a random permutation generator is never guaranteed to generate all permutations.

Answer (score 0):

Random and Unique can't be satisfied together. So assuming you need random *order* of all permutations.

If length of the string is relatively small (so list of results fit in memory) you can generate all permutations first and than shuffle result. This would give pretty decent performance as both operations are linear on size of output..

To get code combine [Smart way to generate permutation and combination of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993073/smart-way-to-generate-permutation-and-combination-of-string?rq=1) and [Random shuffling of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

If you need just one random unique result at a time - your original code to generate random string is ok, but you should use Hashset or similar structure to find duplicates ([Fastest data structure for contains() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267572/fastest-data-structure-for-contains-in-java)).

Note that generating all combination this way is not practical - after about 80% of combinations number of retries will grow prohibitively larger and will be close to number of all combinations by the end.

Alternatively you can convert random numbers to string directly:

1. generate random number from 1 to (numberOfCharacters^LengthOfString),
2. check if it has duplicate in Hashset - go back to 1
3. add number to Hashset
4. convert number to string  (divide by numberOfCharacters till you get to 0 and use reminder on each step to select character)
   19 for "abc":  
   19/3= 6, reminder 1 - add "b" to result
   6/3 = 2, reminder 0 - add "a" to result
   2 - add "c" to result = "bac"